# Iteratee get chunked data (Scala)

Tags: scala, enumeration, loops

I have a lot of data, which are obtained from db by cursor (e.g. 2 mln entries), now I'm using `Iteratee.foreach` but I want to optimize and operate on arrays of object. Is it possible to operate on some chunks, that will read e.g. 1000 documents and then run my code.

```
cursor.enumerate().apply(Iteratee.foreach { doc =>
   ...
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You should just be able to take 1000 and then operate on that.  Lather, rinse, repeat.
I'm guessing it would go here.

cursor.enumerate().apply(Iteratee.take(1000).foreach { doc =>
   ...
})

Comment: I don't have function `take`, I 'm using play framework 2.2 with Scala 2.10